# Singular or plural in the mentioned context?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> Let's now explain the contrast between ethical and unethical **act/acts**

In the above sentence, should it be "act" or "acts"?

Comment: Short answer: acts. Long answer: This isn't even a full sentence - there is no verb (or predicate). And there is no context for the sentence, nor for the question. Are you reading a paper or story? Answering a quiz? Is it your text or someone else's To get good answers, it is best to ask a good question.

Comment: @laugh Now edited.

Answer (score 1):

In your sentence the *plural* should be used

> The contrast between ethical and unethical **acts**.

since there are ethical *acts* and unethical *acts* as two different groups, otherwise it would be

> The contrast between **an** ethical and **an** unethical **act**.

Comment: But I wanted to shorten your last one. What would you do if you wanted not to repeat act in your last phrase?

Comment: @user157323 - Then you could use Peter's first version, "the contrast between ethical and unethical acts".  Or are you saying that you definitely want to use *act* and not *acts*, but you don't want to repeat *act*?

Comment: @stangdon Yes, I want to use act without repeating it.

Comment: @user157323 I don't understand you comment since "***act***" is used only once in the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on context you could drop the reference to acts altogether.  "The contrast between ethical and unethical is that..." makes perfect sense.

Comment: I need to have "act" in the sentence.

Comment: That's why I said "depending on context".  You didn't give any.